# Question on integrable set

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

[image]What is an integrable set?

> "If $T$ is a Hausdorff topological space and $\mu$ is a positive
>   Radon measure on $T$, and if $F$ is a measurable multifunction, then
>   for each ***integrable set*** $T_0\subset T$, and each $\varepsilon > 0$,
>   there existe a compact $T_1\subset T_0$ such that
>   $\mu(T_0-T_1)<\varepsilon$ and $F$ is continuous on $T_1$. That is the
>   Lusin property"

Please.

Thank you.

Comment: The only sensible answer occurring to me is that _integrable set_ is a synonym for _measurable set_. What source does the quoted part come from?

Comment: are you sure ? it's from the book of C.Castain, M-Valadier : convexe and measurable multifunction chapter 3 remark after corollary 3

Comment: Contemplating it more carefully, another good option is that $\int_{T_0} 1 \,\mathrm d\mu < +\infty$ i.e. $T_0$ has finite measure.

Comment: they say that is the Lusin property , do you know something about Lusin property ? please

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know about that, I just know some general measure theory. Sorry for not being of more help.